# How do you transform materials in textures?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a normal and ambient occlusion.

How do I combine them into a single texture? If I render them with nodes in material mode then it looks good.

But in texture mode they look incredibly awful. I want to achieve the same looks from materials into texture mode.

Comment: You need to bake the texture

Comment: @Gorgious What does that mean? if I laready have the normal and ambient occlusion maps then I already baked them? or is there another way to obtain them?

Comment: AFAIK you can only view a single texture in texture display mode, so you'll have to bake the combined color + occlusion maps in another map I think

Comment: @Gorgious and how does that work?

Comment: Just FYI:  when I have baking trouble on a material that looks good while rendering?  I'll hide everything, put a Plane in, put the material on it, put the active camera above it pointing straight down, change the camera from Perspective to Orthographic, and render.  Might need more work in GIMP (or whatever 2D app you like), but often gets the job done.  That having been said, baking is still the way it should be done, Gorgious is right.

Comment: If by "texture mode" you mean, solid view with texture as color, combining these will not make it look any better.  You're not going to make your model look good in every possible display configuration-- these displays are not designed to make models look good, not necessarily, but to reveal information to the artist.